# Print online users to console, Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I execute the command using my current code, I get the error `NameError: name 'offline' is not defined`. I can't find the correct variables to make it work properly.

```
@bot.command()
async def D(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.status != offline:
            print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```

Comment: You are comparing user.status with a variable named `offline`, which of course does not exist

Comment: I know it does not exist, hoping someone knows the correct variable

Comment: I think you are confusing a variable with a value. did you mean `if user.status != 'offline'`?

Comment: It will run, but it does not give the desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status), you could use

```
if user.status != discord.Status.offline
```

PS. I know nothing about this library, yet I tried searching the docs. Give it a try from now on :)

Comment: I tried this one before, I get `NameError: name 'Status' is not defined`

Comment: Please include whatever is relevant, into the question. Saves time :)

Comment: Edited answer according to some code I found around, @UnaTripolla . Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for user in ctx.guild.members:
    if str(user.status) != "offline":
        # your code
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).