# discord.py - Failed if you have status == "online"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hi I'm new to programming stackoverflow and discord bots I made the following code initial to iterate server members who are online of course I understand this option if there are many members then the iteration process can be long and I was wondering why not works, code below, no compilation errors. Previously all my variables were set to null so I didn't paste the below in the code.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global bot_count,online_count
    guild = client.get_guild(my guild id)
    memberList = guild.members

    for members_online in memberList:
        member = members_online.status
        if member == "online":
            online_count = online_count + 1
            print(f"Online: {member}")
```

Comment: Do you mind also translating your question's title? Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, you should take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre] of your specific problem. Your question isn't really clear about what's wrong with your code -- what do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: not added to online_count if status is "online"

Comment: If you're just asking why the process of iterating over lots of members is slow, the answer is because that's just the way it is. And since you need to check each element of `memberList` to see if that member is online or not, there's really no way around this. (I'm not familiar with the discord API, so there might be a way to _just_ get the list of online members, in which case getting its count is a simple `len()` call)

Comment: Well, anyway, this is a process of enumeration, when the user is online, even the print () event is not called, although it should.

Answer (score -2):

Taking a look at a different thread and the API, you might want to be using some of the API docs from [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status) and possibly taking a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853854/print-online-users-to-console-discord-py).

According to the thread, you should try an if statement like so:

```
if user.status != discord.Status.online
```

Comment: Since this question has already been answered, you should flag/vote to close as a duplicate (you have the [reputation](/help/privileges/flag-posts) to do so)